# Leaving Loop before it reaches and without error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Hello I have a list that contains checkbox and with jquery I get checked Items Ids and collecting them in array but my loop ends before all Items checked.Here is controller;

here is getting Array From Url ;

```
public class IntArrayModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return value
                .AttemptedValue
                .Split(';')
                .Select(int.Parse)
                .ToArray();
        }
    }

public ActionResult ApproveSelected([ModelBinder(typeof(IntArrayModelBinder))] int[] id)
    {

        try
        {

            var AllParticipants = Db.Participants
            .Where(m => id.Contains(m.Id))
            .OrderBy(m => m.Id)
            .ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < AllParticipants.Count; i++)
            {

                var item = AllParticipants.First();
                item.Approval = true;

                var itemRemove = AllParticipants.First();
                AllParticipants.Remove(item);

            }

            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { IsComplete = false });
        }

        return Json(new { IsComplete = true });
    }
```

So if I send 1 Id no problem. if I send 2 if changes approvel of the first one then leaves the loop with success message. if I send 2 it changes 2 of then leaves 1. When I go 4 it changes 2 and leaves 2 when I go 5 it changes 3 and leaves 2. its awkward. How Can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllParticipants.Count; i++)
        {

            var item = AllParticipants.First();
            item.Approval = true;

            var itemRemove = AllParticipants.First();
            AllParticipants.Remove(item);

        }
```

To this:

```
Db.Participants
  .Where(m => id.Contains(m.Id))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(participant=>participant.Approval=true);

Db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You were fetching the first, from collection, then removing it from the collection. Then increment the index by 1, so real you were skipping one each time.